# mod rewrite - img paths without extensions

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess

I am using mod rewrite to strip URL of the .php extension, but the client wants me to go even further and strip of extensions all src paths in `<img>`. Is this doable via .htaccess, or maybe php? The only way I can think of now is JS but he wants it server side.

Comment: If your images are in thesame directory, you could just rewrite `^(.*).jpg$ to path/to/images/$1`

Comment: @Gudgip No, because you'd still be requesting it using the extension...

Comment: Store your image filenames in a database and give each image a unique name or ID.  From there, create a script that retrieves that returns the image with the correct header depending on the name/id passed from the URL

Comment: hmm, do something like imagenameIMG -> imagename.jpg (assuming all images have thesame extention)

Comment: http://community.sitepoint.com/t/mod-rewrite-to-find-images-without-extensions/16959

Comment: @Gudgip This could help or at least point me in the right direction but the problem is that the images aren't always jpgs. It should combine the filename with all possible extensions for img and return the one that exists (names are unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.htaccess` file with the following line:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Then you can access the files within a directory without the extension, as long as your filenames are unique it should work OK.

The .htaccess file should be placed at the lowest level within your file structure that you want this behaviour to occur.

This will work for all extension!

Comment: Just as stated in the link I posted ;-)

Comment: I found it here... http://pressedweb.com/tutorials/remove-file-extensions-with-htaccess-and-multiviews/